# on_voice_state event issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want bot to create a text channel when someone joins voice channel.

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(ctx, member: discord.Member, before, after):
    channelid = after.channel.id
    print(f'{member.name} заходит в голосовой канал с ID = {channelid}...')
    if channelid == 764768330212048941:
        print(f'{member.name} зашел в "Стрим 1"(ID: {channelid})')
        print(f'Создаю текстовый канал с именем: "Стрим 1|{member.name}"')
        await ctx.create_text_channel(name=f'Стрим 1|{member.name}')
    else:
        if channelid == 764843714417655808:
            print(f'{member.name} зашел в "Стрим 2"(ID: {channelid})')
```

When I am joining vc I get this:

```
TypeError: on_voice_state_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'after'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `ctx` parameter in events and you don't have to do `member: discord.Member` because it's already assigned. If you want to create channel, you can use [`Guild.create_text_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel). For doing this, you need to get `guild` object with `discord.utils.get`. Here is an example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    channelid = after.channel.id
    print(f'{member.name} заходит в голосовой канал с ID = {channelid}...')
    if channelid == 764768330212048941:
        print(f'{member.name} зашел в "Стрим 1"(ID: {channelid})')
        print(f'Создаю текстовый канал с именем: "Стрим 1|{member.name}"')
        guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, id=your guild id)
        await guild.create_text_channel(name=f'Стрим 1|{member.name}')
    else:
        if channelid == 764843714417655808:
            print(f'{member.name} зашел в "Стрим 2"(ID: {channelid})')
```